# Use roxygen2 to export a variant function

Tags: r, roxygen2, package-development

When I use `@describeIn` or `@rdname` to document a variant of a function, the variant doesn't get exported. Is there a tag I can place in the roxygen skeleton to change this, or do I need to go directly into the NAMESPACE?

```
#' Title
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
foo <- function() {
  "foo"
}

#' @rdname foo A variant
#'
#' @export
bar <- function() foo()
```

When I attach this package, I can call `foo` just fine, but trying to call `bar` results in `Error: could not find function "bar"`.

Comment: Are you greatly opposed to adding `@export` to the roxygen for bar? That's what the @export in your code for foo does for you. It's the same way with an aliased function.

Comment: I tried that, as it seemed the natural thing to do, but it still didn't get exported. I concluded there was some syntactical nuance I was missing.

Comment: Did you rerun roxygen?

Comment: With `devtools::document()`. That should do it, right?

Comment: It should.  If you check your NAMESPACE file has it been modified to include bar? I'm just wondering if you updated your package but forgot to build/install it and tried using the one that is installed locally to test if it worked.

Comment: After some trial and error I happened upon the problem - `@rdname` doesn't like the description text. The mishaps you posit in your last comment might be why it didn't work before I switched from `@describeIn` to `@rdname` though, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line of text after `@rdname foo`. Note the message about "invalid path" given when running roxygen:

```
> devtools::document()
Updating mypackage documentation
Loading mypackage
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing foo.Rd
Skipping invalid path:  foo A variant..Rd
```

This can be fixed by removing that label text:

```
#' @rdname foo
#' @export
```

Or by using `@describeIn`:

```
#' @describeIn foo A variant.
#' @export
```